# Can I generate a service contract diagram

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wssf

So using (the old  Microsoft Patterns and Practices) ["Web Service Software Factory 2010"](http://servicefactory.codeplex.com/), I am able to create a new service contract diagram from scratch. i.e.
[image: http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/brijmohan/image_thumb_11A7781A.png]

That is then able to be used to generate code....

I however, want to come from the other end and generate a Service Contract diagram from existing services, contracts/interfaces, methods/operations, messages, faults etc.

Is this possible? What is the best tool to do this?

Answer (score 2):

How badly do you want this feature? If you only need an initial reverse-engineering step, then you could extend the WSSF yourself. I have done something like this to permit the creation of the data contract model from existing classes. It wasn't easy, but in my case, it was worth it.

---

Readers unfamiliar with WSSF may think it's a packaged solution. It's not. It's built on a platform that is extremely extensible, using the Guidance Automation Toolkit from Microsoft Patterns & Practices, three Domain Specific Languages, code generation through T4 templates, etc. Many extensions can be created simply in XML.

This feature would require perhaps five pages of code.

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the question ;-)

Comment: Actually, it does answer the question, it just doesn't give all the code necessary to accomplish it.

Comment: I don't see how. "Can I generate a service contract diagram? Is this possible? What is the best tool to do this?"

Comment: They can generate such a diagram if they write the code to do so. Are you familiar with WSSF and how extensible it is?

Comment: Not really, but if a valid answer to questions like this is "Write it yourself", then I don't understand this site very well because that's a valid answer to almost every question.

Comment: In most cases, it's not _possible_ to write it yourself. WSSF is sufficiently extensible that it _is_ possible, and I have done so. Keep in mind, he was asking for something to work _within_ WSSF - just a different way to create the service contract model.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8863/discussion-between-pabloc-and-john-saunders)

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not supported and there are no plans to support it.

http://servicefactory.codeplex.com/workitem/5271